# Why do I have to encode a string when reading and writing form inputs using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, encoding

I am programatically reading data from a text input using standard Jquery like this:

```
  var listName = $('#list').val();
```

and then I am adding a hidden input field into a form before submitting like this:

```
var myForm = $("#myForm);
myForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="List" value="' + listName + '" />');
```

In one example,  the value in the field is:

```
Key Date & Times
```

so on the UI it looks like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyList" value="Key Date & Times" />
```

when I submit the form using:

```
var myForm = $("#myForm);
myForm.submit();
```

and check it on the asp.net-mvc server side i only see:

```
Key Date
```

being sent over.  After some research, it was suggested to write some javascript to run the value through:

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

After doing that and taking a look at the server side, I now see:

```
Key%20Date%20%26%20Times
```

How can I convert that back to

```
Key Date & Times
```

on the C# asp.net-mvc server side?  Or Seperately, if I am doing something wrong on the client side, please let me if you have any suggestions.

My main question is why do i have to worry about encoding the value of a hidden input box in a form.  I would have thought this would be taken care of for you.

Comment: It is quite likely you are doing something wrong on client side... But you've shown no code.

Comment: I am not sure what other Code to show.  I have a form with the hidden input above and I can calling Form.Submit via jquery.  What other code do you think would be helpful here?

Comment: If you are doing a normal http post form submit, i do not think you need to do anything specific to address this. It should work! Are you hijacking the form submit event and making an ajax GET request ?

Comment: @Shyju - I am simply calling: $("myForm").submit(); from jquery (no ajax).  The only thing that i am doing that is not plain vanilla is reading a value from a textbox and putting that value into a hidden input programatically before calling form submit((

Comment: I cannot repeat this behavior at all.

Comment: This can easily be tested with any modern browser by creating a form with those inputs, and submitting it, and then checking the URL in the network tab to see that it was urlencoded properly, and [**all tests**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/722bp7at/) show `&List=Key+Date+%26+Times` being sent properly. So the answer is simly ***"no"***, neither jQuery or hidden inputs makes a difference, the data is sent just as any other regular input in a form, and should be available on the server in the same way any other data from a form would be.

Comment: Try to post your form insteed :))

Comment: @LaurentLequenne - see my comment above. I am doing a regular form post

Comment: @leora: hi, I've replicate your code but I don't encounter your issue. Have you some settings for jQuery or other script? Or some other non standard settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
string decodeString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(@"Key%20Date%20%26%20Times");
```

Use `UrlDecode` method of `HttpUtility` class.

Comment: **Note:** `using System.Web` is required.

Answer (score 2):

There's *something wrong on client-side*. I've tested the following code which is like one you wrote and **worked fine**!

```
<input type="hidden" id="ref" value="Key Date & Times" />
<form id="form1" action="~/home/handle" method="post">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    var myForm = $('#form1');
    var listName = $('#ref').val();
    myForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' + listName + '" />');
</script>
```

You have no need to use conversion tools!

Comment: @leora I completely changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think **no need to do any thing with your code**, it works properly, i have folow below code, please confirm it.

**View/Html:**

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm", name = "myForm" }))
{
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Click" id="btnClick">
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myForm = $("#myForm");
    myForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="List" value="Key Date & Times" />');

    $('#btnClick').click(function () {
        var myForm = $("#myForm");
        myForm.submit();

    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Save()
{
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: no difference between using `Request["List"]` and `string List` as action argument! She can't get the proper `List` value if she can't get it from action argument.

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you use GET method to submit a form (in GET method '&' acts as a variable separator) you have to use POST method or String manipulation.

if you are using `encodeURIComponent()` you can convert it back using `Server.UrlDecode("");` on server side

you can also read this for extra knowledge [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely you are submitting a GET request to the server, and therefore all values of each input form fields are posted to the server in the query string.

In this way, as already said by [Zulqarnain Jalil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39910432/3762855), every '&' it is interpreted by the server as a separator of the key/value pairs in the query string, and so you miss the last part of your "List" hidden input form field.

Hence, in this case you have to url-encode all your values with "&" char.

Instead, if you submit a POST request to the server, you needn't to do any url-encoding of form field values, because they are passed to the server separately, namely not in the same string.

If you want to avoid url-encoding try to transform your request in a POST request:

```
var myForm = $("#myForm");
myForm.method = "post";
myForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use. There is typo at `var myForm = $("#myForm");`

```
string decodeString = Server.UrlDecode("Key%20Date%20%26%20Times");
```

OR

```
string decodeString = Uri.UnescapeDataString("Key%20Date%20%26%20Times");
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this has to do with implementing security against Cross Site Scripting attacks (XSS).  You need to encode all html input fields that will be used in the post request.  Otherwise someone could add domaliciousStuff() to a text field and it would be stored in the database.  Then when the data is displayed on the form again, your script (now saved in the database, will run on the web page!).

AntiXSS is a great library that possesses more capabilities than the built-in Html.Encode.  You can find it via Nuget Package Manager.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/

Answer (score 0):

Your main question *encoding the value of a hidden input box in a form* can be answered like this and this is just not pertaining to hidden inputs it relates to any **data** *being posted to the server*.

When data contains spaces and special characters like (&) in your case then it is the responsibility of the application developer to encode it so that the data is safe to be processed by the server. Having spaces and special characters pose security issues like XSS. This is just one of the many steps a responsible developer should take to mitigate such security threats.

Regarding how to get back the values at the server side use the following class found in System.Web namespace

```
string values = "Key%20Date%20%26%20Times";
string decodeString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(values);
```

Hope it answers your question(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add **accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"** in form tag and don't worry about encoding it automatically converts special characters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You can test it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_accept_charset)

Comment: I can see no difference - with or without thé `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` attribute the snippet is showing the same results. E.g. the characters `%&'` are giving the result `fname=%25%26%27&lname=` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 3 to 4 days back. I was working with Angular and ASP.
Like the answers above state I too had to use URLDecode.

> Answering your question:- **Why should I encode user input?**

---

## Avoid Unexpected Behaviour

*Say your application can handle two parameters in a GET request.*

**This only takes in one argument**
`localhost:5000/stalls?searchbook=`

**This takes in two arguments**
`localhost:5000/stalls?searchbook=&includesecret=`

**You also have a page that can search for books.**
Whatever the user types into the search bar results in a GET request.
 `localhost:5000/stalls?searchbook=USERSTRINGGOESHERE`

**If the user were to search for
`&includesecret=true`**
Resultant GET Request `localhost:5000/stalls?searchbook=&includesecret=true` and might accidentally result in private data being leaked to the user on the results page.

Symbols that are normally encoded (spaces, &, % etc) can many a times mean different things. '&' separates keys in a GET request and can also be a part of a string, so using it without encoding can result in expected behaviour.

> P.S:- Private data shouldn't be queried via a GET request. It's just for the sake of this example :)

---

## Consistency

While testing my application I noticed that PhantomJS encoded strings by default. This way I got different search results in different clients. It is therefore *safe to assume* that some clients might encode the URL even if you don't do it.

---

## Another Example

'#' keys can be a part of a URL. If I visit `localhost:5000/homepage.html#footer` the element with the ID footer comes into display. This too can cause lead to behaviour that you do not expect. Try entering # in a GET request parameters that isn't encoded nor is cleaned of non alphabetic characters and you'll most likely end up in a situation similar to mine. The search functionality that I wrote a few days back would break if I entered # in it (when it wasn't encoded).

Answer (score -1):

You can replace all the %20 with spaces.

`string values = "Key%20Date%20%26%20Times";
string decodeString = values.replace(/%20/g,' ');`

Answer (score -1):

you said your main question is:

> why do i have to worry about encoding the value of a hidden input box
>   in a form. I would have thought this would be taken care of for you.

Well, the answer is because otherwise it could lead to injection problems. (Also, hidden fields are not the place for storing sensitive information and I wonder why that input is hidden, also, to be hidden won't change how it behaves...)

In order to fix your issue you could mix htmlEscape and string replace functions, like in the answer to this question ([Encode hidden form field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639604/encode-hidden-form-field-value))

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
        .replace(/&/g, '%26')
        .replace(/ /g, '%20');
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Writing your own escape procedure is a bad bad idea. Use built-in method like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25396011/4494577) instead.